# How to use 2 OpenCL runtimes

Tags: opencl

I want to use 2 OpenCL runtimes in one system together (in my case AMD and Nvidia, but the question is pretty generic).

I know that I can compile my program with any SDK. But when running the program, I need to provide libOpenCL.so. How can I provide the libs of both runtimes so that I see 3 devices (AMD CPU, AMD GPU, Nvidia GPU) in my OpenCL program?

I know that it must be possible somehow, but I didn't find a description on how to do it for linux, yet.

Thanks a lot,
Tomas

Comment: An application cannot load 2 libraries which exports the same functions, but you can run the same app twice, each time loading different libraries:

LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib64/OpenCL/vendors/intel; ./app_to_run
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib64/OpenCL/vendors/amd; ./app_to_run

This is what you want ?

Comment: Cool, that would be one solution. But I really want to use it in one application. With your solution I would have to start 2 apps for each runtime and then connect the apps somehow to use both runtimes in one program... I really hope there is a easier way!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Smith and Thomas answers are correct; this is just expanding on that information: When you enumerate the OpenCL platforms, you'll get one for each installed driver. Within each platform you enumerate the devices. The AMD and Intel drivers also expose CPU devices. So on a fully populated machines, you might see an AMD platform (with CPU and GPU devices), an NVIDIA platform (with GPU device), and an Intel platform (with CPU and GPU devices). Your code creates a context on whichever devices you want to use, and one or more command queues to feed them work. You can keep them all busy working on things, but you can only share data buffers between devices from the same platform. To share data across platforms, it must hit CPU memory in between.

Comment: On the last sentence, I could imagine a vendor extension allowing one to transfer data across, say, an SLI bus if one is available, between two compatible platforms. But in general, yes, it needs to go through system memory, so if your problem can't be neatly split across independent GPU's, multi-GPU computation is going to suck.

Answer (score 6):

You're not thinking of it right. SDK's are not provided by the application, and are *not needed* for running a compiled program. OpenCL **runtimes** are provided by the client system, and that's what's giving your program platforms and devices to use in `clGetPlatformIDs` and `clGetDeviceIDs`.

If the user does not have an Nvidia graphics card, you are simply *not going to be able to use an Nvidia platform and device* on his system, because he doesn't have the Nvidia OpenCL runtime or hardware.

All different OpenCL SDK's provide you are vendor-specific extensions, which are then understood by the vendor runtime.

Comment: Yes, but the target platform has an APU (CPU with integrated GPU from AMD) and a Nvidia GPU. I want to access both within the same program. It will have probably 2 platform IDs, of which one has 2 devices and the other has 1 device.

Comment: Yes, so just acquire both platforms and all three devices from the OpenCL API. You don't need to link to "SDK's", OpenCL will let you access all installed platforms on the system. Do you mean you want to use them at the same time to go faster? If so, it's completely different question and you want to do multi-gpu computation. Is that so?

Comment: Yes, I want to do multi GPU + CPU computation, all with OpenCL. And as said in the comment on my question above, you need to have the LD_LIBRARY_PATH pointing to the libOpenCL.so. With 2 devices from different vendors, you have 2 libOpenCL.so ... the question is how to use both in one application.

Comment: @Tomas You don't have to. Just build with any one of them, and you'll see that when you run your program on your target system, you'll be able to obtain every single device with clGetPlatform/DeviceIDs regardless of the libOpenCL.so you linked with. Try it with a simple program which enumerates platforms and devices.

Comment: @Tomas Basically, the SDK is not the one responsible for compiling kernels and running code, that's the runtime's job. the SDK merely provides slightly modified headers to build against (including vendor extensions and such). If you have the SDK, you generally have the runtime, but users will have only the runtime, which I guess is where your confusion is coming from.

Comment: I cannot really believe this but hopefully I will be able to test it soon. I think the problem is more like Sacx explained it above: one program can only use one runtime. But you are right I have mixed up some terms in my question: I mean using 2 runtimes (not 2 SDKs)

Comment: I still don't understand your problem. You can acquire two devices and work with them in parallel in your program, as needed, just call clGetPlatform/DeviceID's, create contexts as needed, and distribute your workload accordingly. As for runtimes, that's the entire *point* of OpenCL - write your kernel once (no platform-specific hacks), build your program against a generic OpenCL API (maybe using vendor extensions), and distribute this program which will be able to see any current and future OpenCL-compliant devices. You can absolutely use more than one runtime per program.

Comment: For instance, suppose I have an Intel CPU and an AMD graphics card. I compile my program against any OpenCL headers, and when I run it, I can select either the CPU device, or the GPU device (or both) to do work on. It doesn't matter what I built my program against - the OpenCL *loader* is not inside my program but provided by the OS. If I build against the Intel headers, I can't use AMD extensions, but if you use vendor-specific extensions you probably cannot run your code on every device anyhow, so that point is moot.

Comment: I think what I'm really trying to say is that your program is **not** linking against runtimes but against a generic OpenCL interface, which can then serve any available runtime as needed, without needing a rebuild.

Answer (score 5):

The Khronos OpenCL working group defined a ICD layer (installable client driver) that allows multiple vendor drivers to be installed on the system. The application accesses the vendor drivers through the ICD layer. For more details see [cl_khr_icd.txt](http://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/extensions/khr/cl_khr_icd.txt).

Comment: cl_khr_icd.tx has a very well explanation . i search for long time in the internet but i didn't found any thing but with this text file i understand the whole scenario .

Answer (score 2):

In regards to running on multiple OpenCL devices at the same time.  If you want to run on multiple devices create a separate context for each device/vendor and run each one in a separate thread. For example I have a GTX 590.  This shows up as two GTX 590 devices.  I also have the Intel i7 processor.  I create three contexts: two for the 590 devices and one for the CPU and run each context/device in three threads using SDL_CreateThread (pthreads works well as well).  You have to weight the number of jobs for each device proportional to their "speed" if you want to get good results.  For example 45% for each GTX 590 and 10% for the CPU.  The best weights to use depend on the application.