# OpenCL matrix multiplication should be faster?

Tags: performance, opencl, matrix-multiplication, pyopencl

I'm trying to learn how to make GPU optimalized OpenCL kernells, I took example of matrix multiplication using square tiles in local memory. However **I got at best case just ~10-times speedup ( ~50 Gflops )** in comparison to numpy.dot() ( 5 Gflops , it is using BLAS).

I found studies where **they got speedup >200x ( >1000 Gflops )**. 
ftp://ftp.u-aizu.ac.jp/u-aizu/doc/Tech-Report/2012/2012-002.pdf
I don't know what I'm doing wrong, or if it is just because of my GPU ( nvidia GTX 275 ). Or if it is because of some pyOpenCl overhead. But I meassured also how long does take just to copy result from GPU to RAM and it is just ~10% of the matrix multiplication time.

```
#define BLOCK_SIZE 22 
__kernel void matrixMul(
      __global float* Cij, 
      __global float* Aik, 
      __global float* Bkj, 
      __const int ni, 
      __const int nj,
      __const int nk
){
//   WARRNING : interchange of  i  and  j  dimension  lower the performance >2x on my nV GT275 GPU    
int gj = get_global_id(0);    int gi = get_global_id(1); 
int bj = get_group_id(0);     int bi = get_group_id(1);  // Block index
int tj = get_local_id(0);     int ti = get_local_id(1);  // Thread index
int oj = bi*BLOCK_SIZE;       int oi = bj*BLOCK_SIZE; 
float Csub =0; 
__local float As   [BLOCK_SIZE][BLOCK_SIZE];
__local float Bs   [BLOCK_SIZE][BLOCK_SIZE];
for (int ok = 0; ok < nk; ok += BLOCK_SIZE )   {
    As[ti][tj] = Aik[ nk*(gi   ) + tj + ok ];   // A[i][k]
    Bs[ti][tj] = Bkj[ nj*(ti+ok) + gj ];        // B[k][j]
    barrier(CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE);
    for (int k = 0; k < BLOCK_SIZE; ++k) Csub += As[ti][k] * Bs[k][tj];
    barrier(CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE);
}
Cij[ nj * ( gi ) + gj ] = Csub;
```

}

NOTE - the strange BLOCK_SIZE=22 is the maximum BLOCK_SIZE which does fit to max work_group_size which is 512 on my GPU. In this code must hold condition BLOCK_SIZE^2 < max work_group_size. 22=int(sqrt(512)). I tried also BLOCK_SIZE=16 or 8 but it was slower tan with 22.

I also tried simple matrixMul (without using local memory) but it was even 10-times slower than numpy.dot().
I copied the code here 
http://gpgpu-computing4.blogspot.cz/2009/10/matrix-multiplication-3-opencl.html
they say that even the simple version (without local memory) should run 200x faster than CPU? I don't undrestand that.

the dependecne of performance in my case is:

```
N =  220 numpy 3.680 [Gflops] GPU 16.428 [Gflops] speedUp 4.464 
N =  330 numpy 4.752 [Gflops] GPU 29.487 [Gflops] speedUp 6.205 
N =  440 numpy 4.914 [Gflops] GPU 37.096 [Gflops] speedUp 7.548 
N =  550 numpy 3.849 [Gflops] GPU 47.019 [Gflops] speedUp 12.217 
N =  660 numpy 5.251 [Gflops] GPU 49.999 [Gflops] speedUp 9.522 
N =  770 numpy 4.565 [Gflops] GPU 48.567 [Gflops] speedUp 10.638 
N =  880 numpy 5.452 [Gflops] GPU 44.444 [Gflops] speedUp 8.152 
N =  990 numpy 4.976 [Gflops] GPU 42.187 [Gflops] speedUp 8.478 
N = 1100 numpy 5.324 [Gflops] GPU 83.187 [Gflops] speedUp 15.625 
N = 1210 numpy 5.401 [Gflops] GPU 57.147 [Gflops] speedUp 10.581 
N = 1320 numpy 5.450 [Gflops] GPU 48.936 [Gflops] speedUp 8.979
```

NOTE - the "Gflops" number is obtained as N^3/time and it does include time required to copy results from GPU to main memory, but this time is just few percent of total time especially for N>1000

maybe more pictorial is time in secons:

```
N =  220 numpy 0.003 [s] GPU 0.001 [s] load 0.001 [s] speedUp 5.000 
N =  330 numpy 0.008 [s] GPU 0.001 [s] load 0.001 [s] speedUp 7.683 
N =  440 numpy 0.017 [s] GPU 0.002 [s] load 0.001 [s] speedUp 7.565 
N =  550 numpy 0.043 [s] GPU 0.004 [s] load 0.001 [s] speedUp 11.957 
N =  660 numpy 0.055 [s] GPU 0.006 [s] load 0.002 [s] speedUp 9.298 
N =  770 numpy 0.100 [s] GPU 0.009 [s] load 0.003 [s] speedUp 10.638 
N =  880 numpy 0.125 [s] GPU 0.010 [s] load 0.000 [s] speedUp 12.097 
N =  990 numpy 0.195 [s] GPU 0.015 [s] load 0.000 [s] speedUp 12.581 
N = 1100 numpy 0.250 [s] GPU 0.031 [s] load 0.000 [s] speedUp 8.065 
N = 1210 numpy 0.328 [s] GPU 0.031 [s] load 0.000 [s] speedUp 10.581 
N = 1320 numpy 0.422 [s] GPU 0.047 [s] load 0.000 [s] speedUp 8.979
```

I was thinking that maybe some speed improvement can be obtained using 
async_work_group_copy or even read_imageui to copy blocks to local memory. **But I don't understand why I have so big difference when I'm using basically the same code as people who say they have 200x speedup?????**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Without even looking at your code let me make some comments about your benchmarks.  Let's ignore numpy and compare the maximum SP FLOPs/s and DP FLOPs/s of an Intel CPU versus Nvidia and AMD GPUs.

A Intel 2600K at 4 GHz can do 4 GHz * (8 AVX) * (2 ILP) * ( 4 cores) = 256 SP GFLOPs/s.  For DP it's half: 128 DP GFLOPs/s.  Haswell which comes out in a few weeks will double both of those.  The Intel MKL library gets better than 80% efficiency in GEMM.  My own GEMM code gets 70% on my i7-2700 so the 5 GFlops/s you quote with numpy is tiny and not fair to compare with.

I don't know what the GTX 275 is capable of but I would guess it's much more than 50 GFLOPs/s.

The article you reference compares a AMD 7970.  They get 848 (90% efficiency) DP GFlops/s and 2646 (70% efficiency) SP GFlops/s.  That's closer to 10x the performance of the CPU not 200x!

Edit: 
Your calculations of FLOPs is wrong it should be 2.0*n^3.  That's still approximate but it's asymptotically true.  Let me explain.

Consider a 3D dot product.  It's x1*x2+y1*y2+z1*z2.  That's 3 multiplications and two additions.  So a N-dimensional dot product is n multiplications and (n-1) additions.  A matrix product is equivalent to nxn dot products, i.e. n*n*n multiplications and n*n*(n-1) additions.  That's approximately 2.0*n^3 FLOPS. So you should double all your Gflops/s numbers.

Edit:
You might want to consider the kernel time.  It's been awhile since I used OpenCL but using the C++ bindings I did something like this

```
queue = cl::CommandQueue(context, devices[device], CL_QUEUE_PROFILING_ENABLE|CL_QUEUE_OUT_OF_ORDER_EXEC_MODE_ENABLE, &err);
//other code...run kernel

time_end = clevent.getProfilingInfo<CL_PROFILING_COMMAND_END>();  
time_start = clevent.getProfilingInfo<CL_PROFILING_COMMAND_START>();
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks, but my question in ot so much about getting professional bleeding edge performance sgemm/dgemm. I just want too learn how to make quite effective OpenCL kernels **in general**, and matrix multiplication I chose just because it is pretty common example of global memory bottleneck. So I would like some general answer what I'm doing wrong when it is several times slower than it should be. 

I don't have top CPU (I have Core 2 Quad Q9450 at 2.66 GHz) nor top GPU nor highly-optimized MKL/LAPACK instalation (just default numpy in Python(x,y) ). But this is not the point of my question.

Comment: I understand.  But I wanted to fix your comparisons first.  The paper you reference is bleeding edge as you define and you're comparing to something which is far from it.  But anyway, I found a mistake in your Gflops/s calculation.  It should be 2.0*n^3.

Comment: According to wikipedia and other sites the GTX 275 is capable of about 1000 GFlops/s (I assume SP).  You're getting about 100 GFlops/s.  That's a 10% efficiency.  I don't know where your inefficiency is.  I optimized on the CPU so far not the GPU.

Comment: Thanks. Exactly, 50% efficiency would be fine for me, but 10% seems like something is wrong, I just tried matrix multiply from nVidia SDK
https://developer.nvidia.com/opencl and it performs exactly the same as my version of matrixMul (actually the code is almost exactly the same) ... so I'm thinking maybe it is really because of pyOpenCL ( either the compiler does not optimize very well, or python-warper overhead is so large )

Comment: pyOpenCL just sends the kernel to the OpenCL driver which compiles them so pyOpenCL should not effect how the kernel runs.  It could effect the startup overhead.  That's why I think you might want to find the kernel time.  I'm not sure how to do that with pyOpenCL.  I have not used pyOpenCL in over a year.

Comment: yes, it would helpfull to install some OpenCL SDK to analyze the kernels more in-depth. But both AMD and Intel OpenCL SDK doesn't work on nvidia GPUs as far as I know.
btw. camparing to this tutorial/test of sgemm the performance fo my matrixMul seem to be quite average (not so bed)  
http://keeneland.gatech.edu/software/sgemm_tutorial

Comment: 50% efficiency on the CPU took me a long time to reach.  The naive matrix multiplication algorithm that I used and many others still use is only a few % efficient.  Now I get about 70% but that took a lot of effort to figure out.  I image you would face many of the same issues on the GPU.  That paper you reference describes how to get good efficiency on AMD.  You should find one for Nvidia.

Comment: BTW, the Intel and AMD SDK can be used just fine with Nvidia.  I have a GTX 590 and I use all three SDK's.  You should also distinguish between the OpenCL drivers and the SDK.  It's not a problem to install the Radeon driver even if you don't have a AMD GPU.  I use the Intel and AMD drivers to run on the CPU.  It's a lot easy to debug that way.  One problem though is that Nvidia only supports OpenCL 1.1.  I use #define CL_USE_DEPRECATED_OPENCL_1_1_APIS
to help this.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15050043/opencl-sdk-overview-and-hardware-interoperability/15314947#15314947

Comment: If I'm understand you, I can run AMD SDK on CPU if I install AMD drivers. But this would not help me tune performance for GPU in any way? Or will it? Anyway, I understand that debuging kernells on CPU is more convenient (to find errors), even though that it is probably not usefull for performance tuning?

Comment: You need to distinguish between the OpenCL driver for each vendor and the SDKs for each vendor.  They are different things.  If you install the Radeon video drivers you can run your OpenCL kernels on the CPU using AMD.  You could install the AMD SDK and not the Radeon drivers in which case you could compile your OpenCL host code using the AMD SDK but would not be able to run on the CPU using AMD.  I personally use the Intel SDK to develop with and then I run on the CPU using the Intel OpenCL device driver or the AMD radeon device driver and on the GPU using the Nvidia video driver.

Comment: You're correct that Developing your kernel on the CPU will not help you tune it for the GPU.  They are very different devices.

Comment: What about memory bandwidth? Can we use all Gflops limit with a 4-channel 1600MHz memory?

Comment: If I understand your question you want to know the efficiency to expect with the CPU?  Run GEMM with MKL.  You can get a free version with Linux.  MKL gets the best efficiency I have found on the CPU.  I get over 80% on my i7-2600k with MKL for n=1000.  Some claim it should be almost 100%.  I have never seen that.

Answer (score 1):

A good GPU matrix-multiply does not just use local memory, it stores blocks of A, B, and/or C in registers (which results in higher register usage and lower occupancy but is much faster in the end). This is because GPUs have more registers than local memory (128-256KB vs 48KB for NVIDIA), and registers offer as much bandwidth as the ALUs can handle.