# Multiply Matrices in C or in GLSL?

Tags: c, opengl, matrix, gpu, matrix-multiplication

I have an OpenGL program that will be do a fairly good amount of matrix multiplies per second. These will be 4x4 matrices and 128 bytes each. Both my CPU and GPU are pretty up to date (I have a MacBook Pro (Retina, 13-inch, Mid 2014)). I know that GPUs are typically more parallel oriented and might be optimized for this kind of stuff. Would it be faster to have the CPU do the multiplies or my GPU?

Comment: Most times the answer is `GPU is faster for that`. One noticable detail is precision. Most graphics cards do not support double precision and this could lead to precision errors (which could be pretty huge in certain situations).

Comment: @mlkn Darn, then I've got a problem, I will be doing lots of these, so I'll want the GPU for speed, but on the other hand, I need lots of precision because these multiplies will be cumulative, so the CPU would be better for that. hmm...

Comment: There are workarounds for that since people need precision often. For example encoding double with two floats or using iterative algorithms.

Comment: You say 64 bytes each so these are floats (`sizeof(float)*4*4=64)`? But then you say you need precision. So do you really want doubles? This is crucial because the CPU is still quite competitive with most GPUs when it comes to double. You could use [float-float](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadruple-precision_floating-point_format) but that still uses as much space as double.

Comment: @Zboson Sorry about that, didn't do my math correctly. I do want doubles (or 64-bit) floats for my calculations.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16748604/opencl-matrix-multiplication-should-be-faster

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have an OpenGL program that will be do a fairly good amount of matrix multiplies per second.

Define "fairly good amount of matrix multiplies". Keep in mind the CPUs, too are quite capable in doing this kind of computation. With vectorizing instruction set a 4×4 matrix-matrix multiplication boils down to as little as 16 FMA (fused multiply add) instructions. That's not a lot. And given that modern CPUs want to be kept busy as well and often you need the matrices for on-CPU computations as well, it makes a lot of sense to keep the matrix computations on the CPU.

Doing it on the GPU only benefits, if you can parallelize the computation of all those matrices easily. For a single 4×4 matrix-matrix multiply the overhead of loading the matrices onto the GPU and doing the housekeeping easily consumes any performance benefits.